# Check profiles on login django doesn't work

Tags: python, django, authentication

In my project I have two kind of profiles: "Student" and "Professor", in both models I declare an @property like this:

```
class Professor(User):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,   primary_key=True)
    birthday = models.DateField("Data de Nascimento")
    sexChoices = (
        (u"1", "Masculino"),
        (u"2", "Feminino"),
    )
    sex = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = sexoChoices, default = u"1")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    @property
    def perf(self):
    """ This property call the profile name """
        return '%s' % 'Professor'
```

After that I created a method call get_profile(), like this:

```
def get_profile(user):
""" defines the kind of profile
Example: 
    from roles.models import *
    user = User.objects.all()
    profile = get_profile(user[1])
    profile.perfil
"""
    try:
        professor = Professor.objects.get(username=user.username)
        return professor
    except:
        pass

    try:
        student = Student.objects.get(username=user.username)
        return student
    except:
        pass

    return user
```

In my login view I'm trying to render differents html, for do this i'm using the get_profile() and perf property, like this:

```
class LoginValidator(View):

    def post(self, request,  **kwargs):

    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'Logado com sucesso')
            if( get_profile(user).perf  == 'Professor'):
                return render(request,'professor/home.html')

            return render(request,'student/home.html')

    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Usuário não encontrado')
```

So my question is: why is this methods doesn't work? Has a better way to implement this?

I'm also satisfied with alternatives ways.

Obs:. I'm using Django 1.11 and Python 3.5.2

Comment: `perfil` is not defined.  Is this a typo?
Is there a reason for not simply using another field for `profile` in which the options are `professor` and `student`?  That would make your life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using hasattr() property works well with OneToOneField. [see here in doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships)

Simply put this piece of code in your models.py

```
def get_profile(self):
    if(hasattr(self, 'profile')):
        return self.profile
    return None
```

**Note:**
You're using **Professor** as a OneToOne field. I'm using **profile** here because I'm assuming that there would be more than one type of Models, one being **professor**. Also,  I don't see a related_name attribute in your profile field. Put a related_name attribute as:

```
 user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,   primary_key=True, related_name = 'profile')
```

Quoting from the docs: **You can also use hasattr to avoid the need for exception catching:**

This method will work with the **User** model object. It is so because **User** model object has a OneToOne relation with a **profile** model object.
Hope this helps. Thanks.